# Chamando função delete no botão com onclick

Tags: php, html, css

Quero aperta o botão APAGAR e exclui X dados do banco de dados

esse é o meu tipo_produto.php

```
<?php require("header.php"); ?>
<?php require("menu.php"); ?>

<?php 
require ("model/tipo_itens.php");
$modTipoItens = new TipoItens();
$registros = $modTipoItens->getAll();

?>

    <div class="container">
         <center><h1>Categorias</h1></center>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href='tipo_produto_novo.php'">Nova Categoria</button>
         <table class="table table-striped"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>#</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Descrição</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>     
                <?php foreach ($registros as $registro) { ?>
                    <tr> 
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?></th> <td><?php echo $registro['nome']; ?></td> <td><?php echo $registro['descricao']; ?></td> 
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" onclick="editar(<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
                            <button type="button" onclick="delete(<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button>
                        </td> 
                    </tr> 
                <?php } ?>                      
            </tbody> 
         </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function editar(id){
        window.location.href="tipo_produto_novo.php?id="+id;
    }
    </script>

<?php require("footer.php"); ?>
```

Quando eu clicar no button APAGAR, quero excluir o item selecionado pelo ID.

esse é o meu controller tipo_itens.php

```
<?php
require ("../model/tipo_itens.php");
call_user_func($_GET['acao']);

function inserir(){
    $modTipoItens = new TipoItens();
    $resultado = $modTipoItens->inserir($_POST);    
    header('Location: /exemplo/tipo_produto.php');
    exit;
}

function editar(){
    $modTipoItens = new TipoItens();
    $resultado = $modTipoItens->editar($_POST); 
    header('Location: /exemplo/tipo_produto.php');
    exit;
}

function delete(){
    $modTipoItens = new TipoItens();
    $resultado = $modTipoItens->delete($_POST);
    header('Location: /exemplo/tipo_produto.php');
}

?>
```

e essa é a minha função delete no model tipo_itens.php

```
   function delete($id){
      $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'estoque');
      $id = (int) $id;
      $result = mysqli_query($conexao,"delete from tipo_itens where id_tipo= ".$id);      
      return $result;
   }
```

Não to conseguindo enviar o parametro do ID quando clico no botão e executar a função delete do meu model/tipo_itens.php

Comment: Experimente assim: <button type="button" onclick="editar('<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button> <button type="button" onclick="delete('<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>')" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button> Indique que erro aparece se não der.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes. Há um erro de sintaxe aqui:

```
<button type="button" onclick="delete(<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>" 
class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button>
```

Pois falta fechar o parentese (`)`) em `delete(<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>)`. Resolvendo isso ainda haverá um problema relacionado ao uso da palavra reservada [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). Isso pode ser resolvido mudando o nome da função de `delete()` para, por exemplo, `remover()`.Então fica assim:

```
<button type="button" onclick="remover(<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>)" 
class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button>
```

Como você não colocou a implementação da função `remover()` (antigo `delete()`), imagino que também seja um dos problemas. Então, para enviar a variavel id passada para a função remover (usando o metodo post do http) é necessario (mais interessante) usar **[ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)**. Uma forma nativa de fazer isso em javascript é utilizando a api [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Aplicando ao seu caso a implentação da função remover, usando a api fetch, ficaria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function remover(id){

    var formulario = new FormData();
    /*simula a existencia de um formulario, 
    onde o primeiro parametro é a chave (name) e o segundo o valor (value), 
    fazendo analogia com um campo input de um form*/

    formulario.append('id', id);

        fetch("/tipo_itens.php?acao=delete",
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: formulario
    })
    .then(function(resposta){ return resposta.text(); }).then(function(resposta){ 
   //faça algo com a resposta, por exemplo dizer "Salvo com sucesso!"
   alert(resposta);
```

});
        }

No codigo acima, a url `/tipo_itens.php?acao=delete` acessara um arquivo chamado tipo_itens.php presente no diretorio raiz do servidor (altere conforme a necessidade), algo como `http://localhost/tipo_itens.php`.

Ao fazer a sequencia de passos acima o restante do seu codigo deve funcionar adequadamente. No mais, sempre use o debug do navegador (para ver as respostas de requisições ajax).

Por fim um pequeno exemplo:

```
Arquivo layout.php:

<?php
$registro['id_tipo'] = 2;
?>

<button type="button" onclick="remover(<?php echo $registro['id_tipo']; ?>)" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function remover(id){

        var formulario = new FormData();
        formulario.append('id', id);

            fetch("/tipo_itens.php?acao=delete",
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: formulario
        })
        .then(function(resposta){ return resposta.text(); }).then(function(resposta){ 
    //faça algo com a resposta, por exemplo dizer "Salvo com sucesso!"
    alert(resposta); 
    });
}
</script>
```

Arquivo tipo_itens.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo 'Operação realizada com sucesso! Recebido id ' . $_POST['id'] 
        . ' usando a ação ' . $_GET['acao'];
}
```